# Убрать пробел между изображениями в DIV

Tags: html

Есть код.
Нужно убрать пробелы между изображениями. Как?!

ps, поправил код но вот что выходит когда письмо прилетает на почту.
Пользуюсь Mozilla Thunderbird и вставкой HTML текста.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2hYk.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/feTV0.png

```html
    <title>7</title>
</head>
<style>  #bot {
            width: 770px;
            height: 51;
            font-size: 0;
            float: left;
        }
        #all {
            width: 770px;
            height: 1148;
font-size: 0;
            float: left;
        }
</style>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <div id="all" style="line-height: 0">
        <div style="width: 770px height: 275px";>
            <img src="http://mascherone.com/images/letter_01.png" "vertical-align: bottom" "line-height: 0">
        </div>
            
        <div style="width: 770px height: 487px";>
            <img src="http://mascherone.com/images/letter_02.png" "vertical-align: bottom" "line-height: 0">
        </div>
        <div style="width: 770px height: 143px";>
            <img src="http://mascherone.com/images/letter_03.png" "vertical-align: bottom" "line-height: 0">
        </div>
        <div id="bot" style="line-width: 0 width: 770px height: 51px">
            <img src="http://mascherone.com/images/letter_04.png" alt="">
            <img src="http://mascherone.com/images/letter_05.png" alt="">
            <img src="http://mascherone.com/images/letter_06.png" alt="">
            <img src="http://mascherone.com/images/letter_07.png" alt="">
            <img src="http://mascherone.com/images/letter_08.png" alt="">
            <img src="http://mascherone.com/images/letter_09.png" alt="">
            <img src="http://mascherone.com/images/letter_10.png" alt="">
            <img src="http://mascherone.com/images/letter_11.png" alt="">
            <img src="http://mascherone.com/images/letter_12.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div style="width: 770px" "height: 192px";>
            <img src="http://mascherone.com/images/letter_13.png" "vertical-align: bottom" "line-height: 0">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>![введите сюда описание изображения][2]
</html>
```

Comment: Надо открыть консольку браузеа и поэкспериментировать со стилями.

Comment: Спасибо. "Очень ценный" совет.

Comment: А еще желательно разобраться что такое `src="http://mascherone.com/images/letter_03.png" "vertical-align: bottom" "line-height: 0"` возможно тут пропущен `style=""` или вместо `:` стоит поставить `=`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**В чем дело?**

Ваши изображения - так называемые инлайновые, т.е. строчные элементы. Они воспринимаются как элемент текста. Поэтому любые пробельные символы между ними будут сконвертированы в один пробел в выводе, как если бы это были просто слова.

**Как с этим бороться?**

У вас есть несколько выходов.

Первый - физически убрать пробельные символы между изображениями. Работает безотказно, но это довольно нелепое требование к системе, которое слишком легко нарушить.

Второй - более приемлимый и менее разрушительный - сделать элементы блочными и так или иначе спозиционировать их горизонтально (проще всего через `float`). Плюсы и минусы очевидны - плюс в том, что все на своем месте, а минус - в обтекаемых блочных элементах, которые могут попортить кровь (а могут и нет) при расположении последующих элементов.

Третий вариант - мой любимый - просто задать `font-size: 0` родительскому элементу. Так как в этом случае все символы становятся нулевого размера и просто исчезают, пробелы ровно так же схлопнутся, оставив все остальные стили как есть.

Comment: Спасибо! Помог мне. Все вышло :)